# Unable to read simple RSS feed

Tags: java, rss, rss-reader

I have a simple code that reads RSS feeds. It used to work OK with the given RSS feed, but for some reason stopped working with the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid document
at com.rometools.rome.io.WireFeedInput.build(WireFeedInput.java:312)
at com.rometools.rome.io.WireFeedInput.build(WireFeedInput.java:234)
at com.rometools.rome.io.SyndFeedInput.build(SyndFeedInput.java:150)
```

This is the code:

```
    URL url  = new URL("http://www.dpreview.com/feeds/reviews/latest");
    XmlReader reader = null;
    try {
        reader = new XmlReader(url);
        SyndFeed feeder = new SyndFeedInput().build(reader);
        System.out.println("Feed Title: "+ feeder.getAuthor());
        for (Iterator i = feeder.getEntries().iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
            SyndEntry syndEntry = (SyndEntry) i.next();
            System.out.println(syndEntry.getTitle());
        }
    } finally {
        if (reader != null)
            reader.close();
    }
```

Anything I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem with URL. Responds with `Object moved to <a href="https://www.dpreview.com/feeds/reviews/latest">here</a>`. That is why exception `Invalid document`.

That means that `XmlReader` does not support 304 redirects.

So if you fix your URL to `https` instead of `http`, everything works.

There was similar [issue](https://github.com/rometools/rome/issues/340#issuecomment-314563457), which says that, you have to deal with redirects your self.

Comment: Thanks @muradm. I wonder why the framework doesn't follow redirects... should be a common use case with RSS feeds...

Comment: As it says in documentation, it works with feeds, but is not focused on transport. It includes very basic http client. If you check `XmlReader` it can read from different sources including streams. So you can plug any type of data source there, like more advanced http client, or some other implementation, exaggerating websocket, raw tcp/ip, database etc.